# "#<NoMethodError: undefined method `permit' for \"derp\":String>",

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def store_params
    params.require(:store).permit(:store)
end
```

I have an entity called store and its only column is also called store. Other frameworks seem to have solutions for this issues, but it's not clear how to do this properly on Rails.

```
{
    "store": "derp"
}
```

I sent the above in a POST request and I am getting a seemingly unrelated error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario the top-level key `store` is expected to have an attribute on it named `store` also.  Try passing `{ "store": { "store": "derp" } }` in your POST request, and see if that works.

Here is some useful documentation on Rails params that might help: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html

Comment: It did work, but is there a way to make it work without having to wrap the params with "store"?

Comment: Wait, nevermind, I just had to remove require. Why in the hell would you use require? I thought require was for requiring a field and not requiring the user to enter a wrapper.

Comment: i think you can, but it might get a little confusing.  Anyway, you can just change store_params to this: `params.require(:foobar).permit(:store)` then pass `{ "foobar": { "store": "derp" } }` to your POST.  i believe this should work

Comment: The thing is that I just wanted to pass { "store": "derp" }. It looks like I just need to remove .require(), which is completely useless if you ask me. Tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: i dont think its useless, it will become very helpful if you want to pass parameters for more than one object type in the same request.  for instance you might at some point want to do `{'store': { 'store': 'derp'}, 'region': { 'name': 'southwest'}, 'manager': {'name': 'foobar'}}`.  notice how `region` and `manager` can both have attributes with the same name now and they wont get mixed up

Comment: please feel free to accept my answer if it solved your problem